# Is silicon oxide=rock?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Are common rock (I.e. Rock from mountain, river, bricks, or even concrete) actually silicon oxides? Or it is just one of compositions?

Answer (score 2):

You ask:

> Are common rocks (e.g. rock from mountains or rivers, bricks, or even concrete) actually silicon oxides? Or it is just one of compositions?

Rocks can contain silicon oxides, but that's not part of what the definition of a "rock" implies. From [an introductory course in geology at the University of Texas at Austin](http://www.geo.utexas.edu/courses/303/303_lab/MineralOverhead.pdf), a rock is defined as:

> Any coherent, naturally occurring substance generally composed of minerals.

That's all there is to it. Whether or not the minerals include silicon oxides has nothing to do with a rock being called a rock.

Answer (score 1):

The latter statement is more accurate. [Rocks](http://www.sandatlas.org/minerals/) are mostly silicates and aluminosilicates; though they do contain silicon and oxygen, they also contain other elements. Silicon oxide *per se*, albeit not uncommon, is a relative minority.

**Upd.** Thought I'd rather include a quote from the link above.

> More than 90% on the crust is composed of silicate minerals. Most
> abundant silicates are feldspars (plagioclase (39%) and alkali
> feldspar (12%)). Other common silicate minerals are quartz (12%)
> pyroxenes (11%), amphiboles (5%), micas (5%), and clay minerals (5%).
> The rest of the silicate family comprises 3% of the crust. Only 8% of
> the crust is composed of non-silicates — carbonates, oxides, sulfides,
> etc.

Quartz is $\ce{SiO_2}$; the rest is more complicated.

Comment: Small addition: concrete which is made of cement is essentially CaO hardened to calcium carbonate. Also has gypsum. There are silicate additives but the main components are not silicates.